# How to implement HOG with trilinear interpolation by Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, object-recognition

I am studying HOG. I have find the code [code1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28689-hog-descriptor-for-matlab) and [code2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46408-histogram-of-oriented-gradients--hog--code-using-matlab) about HOG. However, both of them don't implement trilinear interpolation. I have also read some websites, including [web1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738534/hog-trilinear-interpolation-of-histogram-bins-clarification) and [web2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565412/hog-trilinear-interpolation-of-histogram-bins). I still don't know how to write the HOG code with trilinear interpolation. Is anyone who can help me and provide me Matlab sample code about HOG? Thank you very much for your reply.